# In kitsune, how to create a URL format of a details page of an entity without using k-dl?

Tags: serverless

I am trying to create a ecommerce website in kitsune. I do not want to use the _kid value in k-dl. For example, the typical way to do it is -

```
k-dl="/product/[[product.name.urlencode()]]/[[product.code]]/[[product._kid]]"
```

If i do not want to use the _kid as its a long GUID. I would like to use code as its unique for every product as the identifier of the specific product.

When i define the k-dl as below it gives me an error that i must use _kid in the URL format:

```
k-dl="/product/[[product.name.urlencode()]]/[[product.code]]"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ideal way to implement the object details page URL in kitsune it to have a unique id which is **_kid** along with the **k-object** to get the best performance, as an object in kitsune is uniquely identified by **_kid** which is *auto-generated kitsune id*.

But yes, there is an alternate way to implement the object details page without kitsune unique id (_kid).

If you want to maintain object uniqueness from your side, you can create any unique field in kitsune object and use it as below.
Hence the _kid is mandatory if you are using k-object, you need to remove the k-object attribute from the page.

let's say **product.code** is the unique field that you are maintaining from **K-Admin**, you can use the **k-dl** as below.

```html
<head k-dl="/product/[[product.name.urlencode()]]/[[product_code_param]]">
```

here *[[product_code]]* is a **dynamic variable** from the URL, make sure that you pass the correct value of product code to generate the URL.

now you can get the unique object by just using k-repeat loop as below

```html
<div k-repeat="[[product in business.products]]">
  <div k-show="[[product.code == product_code_param]]"> <!--this will only render if the product code is matching with the url param-->
  
    <p>[[product.name]]</p>
  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can I do a wildcard comparasion instead of using ==